# Solving a differential equation using Laplace transform.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

How can I solve the equation $x''+x=\tan(t)$, $x(0)=0,x'(0)=1$, using the Laplace transform?

I know that $\tan(t)$ has no Laplace transform.

Comment: In that case, why would you want to use the Laplace transform? Variation of parameters would be much easier, not to mention using an "invalid" method (if you are not careful about integrating around singularities) will get you an unuseful result necessarily

Comment: Of course it is much easier with variation of parameters, but I have to solve it using Laplace transform. :(